# How to access attributes on xml feed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api-design

I am trying to parse data from an xml file in my React JS app, but it seems to return a full xml object comprising of 25 or so 'cube' elements. I'm interested in accessing the 'currency' and 'rate' attribute of each cube, and output each of these inside of a dropdown. Is there a way of looping over all the cubes and somehow targeting these? I'm trying to build a currency converter that automatically converts a price entered by the user.

My code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import "../../App.css"

class Countries extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            countrycodes: [],
            exchangerates: []
        };
    }


componentDidMount(){
    fetch('http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml')
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(str => (new window.DOMParser()).parseFromString(str, "text/xml"))
        .then(data => {
            const cubes = data.getElementsByTagName("Cube")
            for( const element of cubes) {
                if (!element.getAttribute('currency')) {
                    continue;
                }

                let countrycodes = element.getAttribute('currency')
                let exchangerates = element.getAttribute('rate')
                this.setState({
                    countrycodes: countrycodes,
                    exchangerates: exchangerates
                })                                
            }
        });       
    }


render() {
    return (

        <div className="container2">
            <div className="container1">
                <select>{this.state.countrycodes.map((country) => {
                    <option>{country}</option>})                                            
                }
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
    }
}

export default Countries;
```

Thanks,

Robert

Comment: Which method do you want to use to get access to the attributes, do you want it onClick or onChange?

Comment: Does this is a drop selection?

Comment: I just want to access them by any means possible!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute):

```
class Countries extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            countryCodes: []
        };
    }


  componentDidMount(){
    fetch({url: 'http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml'})
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(str => (new window.DOMParser()).parseFromString(str, "text/xml"))
        .then(data => {
            const countryCodes = [];
            const cubes = data.getElementsByTagName("Cube");
            for (const element of cubes) {
                if (!element.getAttribute('currency')) {
                    // skip cube with no currency
                    continue;
                }
                countryCodes.push({ 
                    currency:element.getAttribute('currency'),
                    rate: element.getAttribute('rate')
                });
            }
            this.setState({countryCodes});
       });
    }

  render() {

    const options = this.state.countryCodes.map(
        ({currency, rate}) => (<option value={rate}>{currency} - {rate}</option>));
    return (
        <div className="container2">
            <div className="container1">
                <select>
                  {options}
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

To check you can open http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml and run `fetch(...)` directly in browser's console:

[image]

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks, but I get an error saying that 'cubes' is not iterable this way:

Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): cubes[Symbol.iterator] is not a function.

Perhaps it is because I am trying to iterate over an object? :)

Comment: It's probably browser-dependent . However, in my example there is no `[0]` in the end: `const cubes = data.getElementsByTagName("Cube");`, did you use as I wrote?

Comment: Thanks, It worked - I now have the data from the feed! Thank you, you're a genius!

Comment: Hi Alex, for extra bonus points, would you know how to output each of the 'currency' and 'rate' attributes inside of a dropdown? I'm trying to implement this somehow inside of the render method of my component, by setting the 'currency' and 'rate' lists as properties of the state. My current code is as follows (see edited question above):

Comment: @RobertYoung yep, updated. I'd store an array of `currencies - rates` in `state`, and `map` state in `render`.

Comment: thanks - an possible solution, but it seems to return the error, 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined'. 

On this line: const options = this.state.countryCodes.map(
  39 |         ({currency, rate}) => (<option value={rate}>{currency} - {rate}</option>));

Is this something to do with an in-built feature of the react render method, as the first time this.state.countryCodes.map is called (if you console.log its value), its is equal to 'undefined', but on subsequent occasions of the loop, it is an object of arrays that gets filled gradually. Maybe one can check?

Comment: @RobertYoung Yeah, it's the first time render, when data is not loaded... You  need to set it up in `constructor` - in updated answer `countryCodes` is an empty array: `this.state = {
            countryCodes: []
        };`